# What Does "Reduced Modulo N" mean in this context?

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

I am trying to understand a piece of notation used in several papers, the simplest/shortest of which is [this paper](http://calebrascon.info/PDA/Topic4/addresources/WOLA.pdf) by Crochiere.  The equation in question is Equation 7 on the second page:

> $x_m(sR) = \tilde{x}_{((m-sR))_M}(sR)$

followed by the remark:

> where ((n)) denotes n reduced modulo M

In the context of Fourier transforms, DFTs and FFTs, where $x$, $\tilde{x}$, etc are sampled signals, what does "n reduced modulo M" mean?  I've seen that notation elsewhere with essentially the same non-explanation, so it must have been something very obvious in context (and maybe still is) but I am completely failing to grasp it.

Comment: $$\begin{align} ((n))_N \ &\triangleq  \quad n \mod N \\
\\
&= n - N\left\lfloor \frac{n}{N} \right\rfloor \\ \end{align}$$ 

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the `floor()` operator, the largest integer that is no greater than the argument $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the number in the double parentheses is changed to [be between $0$ and $M-1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) by adding to or subtracting from it $M$ an integer number of times.

---

See equation (5) of the paper:

$$
\stackrel{\large x}{\sim}_m(sR) = \sum_{l=-\infty}^{+\infty} x(sR+lm+m)h(-lm-m) \tag{5}
$$

so the modulo version is just the time-aliased copies of $x$ summed over the interval of interest, $M$.

The diagram below attempts to illustrate this with $M=4$ (though the image only shows four subsequences, all subsequences should be summed).

[image]

Comment: Bear with me:  So if I had some signal $x(n)$ with thousands of samples, but M was some small number like 16, then I'm just cycling through a set of 16 points even as the index increases well outside that range?

Comment: @Novak No worries! Please see my addition to attempt to explain the detail of what's happening.

Comment: Ah, I think I see-- that's just a shorthand for the combined operation of "Window, and slide window back to origin".  Which, in context, makes sense.  Thank you!